# erro monero daemon fluorine

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

boas
eu tou tendo este problema no gui wallet no relatorio do daemon aparece a seguinte mensagem
2024-01-28 22:49:45.242 I Monero 'Fluorine Fermi' (v0.18.3.1-release)
Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

alguem me consegue ajudar?